# Creating a Link to a Document via a workflow

Tags: 2013, list, workflow

This is with SPO 2013.

I am trying to make it so that when you add a file to a library it will add a Link to a Document content type in a list. If I tell the workflow to add a document to the list it will work just fine. However, when I try to create a Link to a Document item it freezes up.

When creating the item I use the fields:
Content Type ID - Link to a Document
Path and Name (*) - Current Item:Name
URL - Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL

Any insight would be greatly appreciated even if it's simply telling me it's not possible!